# Not allowing me to enter a specific grade for a student in my information system project

Tags: c, arrays, string, visual-studio

My code asks me to enter names from a .txt file then if the names are valid i can log in.

When the program launches the user should be presented with three options;
Press 0 to exit
Press 1 for author info
Press 2 to Log in
Selecting 0 exits the program
Selecting 1 prints your name and student id
Selecting 3 prompts the user to enter a user name and password.
You should then open the file "passwords" and see if the user is authorized to use the program*

I have done this so far. Once i have successfully  logged in I can press option 2 to add a new student. I have done that so far. Now I have made a mistake for option 4. Option 4 asks me to enter a grade for the student. After hitting option 4 it asks me for the grade, whenever i enter a grade the program just crashes on me. I am not sure what my error is.

```
//This is my code:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

/* Constants used in the application */
const char * PASSWORD_FILE = "passwords.txt";
const int MAX_STUDENTS = 1000;
const int MAX_GRADES = 100;
const int MAX_CHARS = 25;

//Function to print Author Info
void printAuthorInfo();

//Function to display initial Menu and Get the User's Selection
int showMainMenu();

//Function to Login to the System
int login();

//member menu
int memberMenu();

//Enter GPA for current Student
void enterGPA(char ids[1000][25], float grades[1000][100], int[], int);

//Display student records to stdout
void print(char[1000][25], char[1000][25], char[1000][25], float[1000][100],     
int[], int);

//Save Records to File
void save(char[1000][25], char[1000][25], char[1000][25], float[1000][100],     
int[], int);

//Load Records from File
void load(char fn[1000][25], char ln[1000][25], char ids[1000][25], float   
grades[1000][100], int counts[], int num);

int main()
{
    int loggedIn = 0;
    int choice, subChoice;
    char firstNames[1000][25];
    char lastNames[1000][25];
    char ids[1000][25];
    float grades[1000][100];
    int numGrades[1000];
    char fn[25];
    char ln[25];
    int numStudents = 0;

    //Top Level Loop
    do {
        //display menu and get the user's selection
        choice = showMainMenu();

        if (choice == 0)
        {
            printf("Thank you for using our Application! GoodBy!");
        }
        else if (choice == 1)
        {
            printAuthorInfo();
        }
        else if (choice == 2)
        {
            loggedIn = login();

            if (loggedIn == 1)
            {
                printf("Welcome! You are now Logged In\n");

                //Interact with the user
                do
                {
                    subChoice = memberMenu();

                    if (subChoice == 1)
                    {
                        printAuthorInfo();
                    }
                    else if (subChoice == 2)
                    {
                        printf("Enter First Name: ");
                        scanf("%s", firstNames[numStudents]);
                        printf("Enter Last Name: ");
                        scanf("%s", lastNames[numStudents]);
                        printf("Enter Student ID: ");
                        scanf("%s", ids[numStudents]);
                        numStudents++;
                        printf("Student Has been added to System");
                    }
                    else if (subChoice == 3)
                    {
                        enterGPA(ids, grades, numGrades, numStudents);
                    }
                    else if (subChoice == 4)
                    {
                        print(firstNames, lastNames, ids, grades, numGrades, 
    numStudents);
                    }
                    else if (subChoice == 5)
                    {
                        void save(firstNames, lastNames, ids, grades, counts, 
    numStudents);
                    }
                    else if (subChoice == 6)
                    {
                        load(firstNames, lastNames, ids, grades, numGrades, 
    &numStudents);
                    }
                    else if (subChoice == 7)
                    {
                        printf("\nYou are logged Out Now");
                    }
                    printf("\n");
                } while (subChoice != 7);
            }
            else
            {
                printf("Login Failed - Try again");
            }
        }
        printf("\n\n");
    } while (choice != 0);


    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

void printAuthorInfo()
{
     printf("Author Information\n");
     printf("Author Name: %s\n", "myinfo ");
     printf("Student ID: %s\n", "12345");
}

int showMainMenu()
{
    //User Selection
    int choice;

    do
    {
        //Display menu
        printf("Press 0 to exit\n");
        printf("Press 1 for Author Info\n");
        printf("Press 2 for Login\n");
        printf("Enter choice? ");

        //Read the selection
        scanf("%d", &choice);
        printf("\n");
    } while (choice < 0 || choice > 2);

   //Return selection
   return choice;
}

int login()
{
    //Get User's username and password
    char username[30];
    char password[30];
    char usernameInFile[30];
    char passwordInFile[30];
    int valid = 0;

    //Prompt and get Username
    printf("Enter Username: ");
    scanf("%s", username);

    //Prompt and get Password
    printf("Enter Password: ");
    scanf("%s", password);

    //Open the input file
    FILE * fptr = fopen(PASSWORD_FILE, "r");

    while (fscanf(fptr, "%s %s", usernameInFile, passwordInFile) == 2)
    {
        if (strcmp(username, usernameInFile) == 0 && strcmp(password, 
    passwordInFile) == 0)
        {
            valid = 1;
        }
    }

    fclose(fptr);
    return valid;
}


int memberMenu()
{
    int choice = 0;

    do
    {
        printf("Press 1 for author info\n");
        printf("Press 2 to Enter new student\n");
        printf("Press 3 to enter grade for existing student\n");
        printf("Press 4 to print student records\n");
        printf("Press 5 to save student records\n");
        printf("Press 6 to load student records\n");
        printf("Press 7 to logout\nEnter Selection? ");
        scanf("%d", &choice);
        printf("\n");

    } while (choice < 1 || choice > 7);

    return choice;
}

void print(char fn[1000][25], char ln[1000][25], char ids[1000][25], float  
    grades[1000][100], int counts[], int num)
{
    int i, j;
    float sum, avg;
    sum = 0;
    avg = 0;

    printf("%-15s %-15s %-10s %-8s %-8s\n", "First Name",
        "Last Name", "Std ID", "GPA", "Grades");

    for (i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        printf("%-15s %-15s %-10s", fn[i], ln[i], ids[i]);

        for (j = 0; j < counts[i]; j++)
        {
            sum += grades[i][j];
        }

        avg = sum / counts[i];
        sum = 0;
        printf("%-8.2f", avg);
        for (j = 0; j < counts[i]; j++)
        {
            printf("%-6.2f", grades[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void save(char fn[1000][25], char ln[1000][25], char ids[1000][25], float   
    grades[1000][100], int counts[], int num)
{
    int i, j;
    float sum, avg;
    char fname[100];
    sum = 0;
    avg = 0;

    //Get file name
    printf("Enter Output File Name: ");
    scanf("%s", fname);

    FILE * fptr = fopen(fname, "w");

    fprintf(fptr, "%d\n", num);
    for (i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        fprintf(fptr, "%s %s %s %d ", fn[i], ln[i], ids[i], counts[i]);

        for (j = 0; j < counts[i]; j++)
        {
            fprintf(fptr, "%.2f ", grades[i]);
        }
        fprintf(fptr, "\n");
    }

    fclose(fptr);
}

void load(char fn[1000][25], char ln[1000][25], char ids[1000][25], float 
    grades[1000][100], int counts[], int * num)
{
    char fname[100];
    int cur = *num;
    int i, j, n, numStudents = 0;
    float grade;

    //prompt and get input file
    printf("Enter Input File Name: ");
    scanf("%s", fname);

    //open file to read
    FILE * fptr = fopen(fname, "r");
    fscanf(fptr, "%d", &numStudents);
    for (i = 0; i < numStudents && cur < 1000; i++)
    {
        fscanf(fptr, "%s %s %s %d", fn[cur], ln[cur], ids[cur], &n);
        for (j = 0; j < n && counts[i] < 100; j++)
        {
            fscanf(fptr, "%f", &grade);
            grades[i][counts[i]] = grade;
            counts[i] += 1;
        }
        cur += 1;
    }

    *num = cur;
    fclose(fptr);

}

void enterGPA(char ids[1000][25], float grades[1000][100], int counts[], int 
    num)
{
    char id[25];
    int i, idx;
    float gpa;

    idx = -1;

    printf("Enter Student ID: ");
    scanf("%s", id);

    //find student
    for (i = 0; i < num && idx == -1; i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(id, ids[i]) == 0)
        {
            idx = i;
        }
    }

    if (idx >= 0)
    {
        printf("Enter Grade: ");
        scanf("%f", &gpa);
        grades[idx][counts[idx]] = gpa;
        counts[idx] += 1;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("NO Such Student Exist In The System");
    }
}
```

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: @BJMyers This is going to be hard for them to debug because it's a fair bit larger than 20 lines, but the advice is still applicable.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 issues that I can immediately see.

1. in the print function you have

   ```
   printf("%-6.2f", grades[i];
   ```

   Since `grades` is a 2D array it should be

   ```
   printf("%-6.2f", grades[i][j]
   ```
2. The function declaration for `load` is incorrect. It should be

   ```
   void load(char fn[1000][25], char ln[1000][25], char ids[1000][25],
      float grades[1000][100], int counts[], int *num);
   ```

   (Note the `int* num`)

There may be other issues, but without the input text files it is difficult to find out.

Comment: This did not make me able to enter a grade for the student.